# Arduino 2's complement read error

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I have this code from a slave device

```
byte buf[] = {125, 126, 127, 2000, 5000};

void setup() {
  // initialize serial:
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  int i = Serial.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
  Serial.println(i);
  delay(5000);

}
```

and I have this code from a listening device.

```
char protocol[5];
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  memset(protocol, '\0', sizeof(protocol)); 
}


void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()) {
  Serial.readBytes(protocol, 5);
  Serial.println(protocol);
  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(protocol); i ++ ) {
    Serial.println((int)protocol[i], BIN); 
  }
  }
  else{
   Serial.println("None available");
   delay(500); 
  }

}
```

I understand that Arduino uses 2's compliment, however the problem I am getting is that the print out is this

```
1111101
1111110
1111111
11111111111111111111111111010000
11111111111111111111111110001000
```

and because of the 2's complement, all zeros are being added to finish the char because the left most bit read in as a 1. Anyways, the 4th and 5th numbers are not 2000 and 5000 but numbers much different than that. How do I get the the appended 1's to go away so I read 2000 and 5000? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are storing and transmitting each number as an 8-bit value, which is not large enough to store the numbers 2000 or 5000.

To fix this, you'll want to change the types of your buffer arrays to `int[`]. Here's how:

In the slave, you'll need to change the line where you declare your buffer:

```
int buf[] = {125, 126, 127, 2000, 5000};
```

And now that the type is different, you'll have to add a type cast, since `Serial.write` expects a `char` or `byte` array.

```
int i = Serial.write((char *) buf, sizeof(buf));
```

Then, you'll have to make similar changes in the listener device. Declare your `protocol` array like so:

```
int protocol[5];
```

Then, `Serial.readBytes` also expects a byte array, so you'll need another cast (and `sizeof` to get the correct number of bytes to read):

```
Serial.readBytes((byte *) protocol, sizeof(protocol));
```

**Edit:** To explain how the `(char *)` cast in the slave works and why it's necessary, remember that this is C++, so (like in C) an array is pretty much a pointer internally. So, when you create the array of five `int`s, what's really going on is you've reserved 10 bytes of memory (enough for five 16-bit `int`s) and received a pointer to the start of it. Now, unless told otherwise, C++ will treat that memory like it's five `int`s. However, it's perfectly happy to treat it as 10 `char`s if you tell it to. This is pretty convenient, since `Serial.write` will only take an array of `char`s (which, as you recall, is like a `char` pointer, hence `char *`). And this will work fine, since it'll send the 10 bytes across the line as `char`s, where the listener will put the same 10 bytes into the `protocol` array. Then, with an exact copy of the 10-byte block of memory, the `protocol` array will have the same `int`s as the `buf` array did in the slave.

One last comment: You may want to have your listener wait until there are actually `sizeof(protocol)` bytes available before trying to read. Otherwise, if only part of the data is ready, it will go ahead and try to read, but `Serial.readBytes` usually only waits a short time for the remaining data before giving up and leaving the buffer unfilled. You would fix that by adding `>= sizeof(protocol)` to the appropriate line:

```
if(Serial.available() >= sizeof(protocol)) {
```

Comment: do you mind explaining what the (Char *) actually does? does it use the start address of the int array?

Comment: @DRAN Sure. I added some explanation to my answer. Hopefully it helped, but if I didn't explain well enough, just let me know.

Comment: @Dominick, Sir can you tell me whether I could send float values with this method? Using the Char * cast?

Comment: @kinath_ru There should be no problem with that. The technique would still be the same.